# Having Clause/Group Gy Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, grouping, aggregate-functions

Im looking to select support agent name, a label that was added to a case (the bottom 10 labels based on an average rating for all cases that have the corresponding label per agent), and the average rating for that label. So the format should be

```
agent name | Label name  | average rating for the label on this row
agent name | label 2 name| average rating for the label in this row
```

I tried this:

```
select a.public_name, label_name, format(avg(r.rating),2) as 'average', count(label_name)
from bi.support_agents_list a 
    join bi.support_ratings_agents sra 
    on a.desk_id = sra.agent_desk_id
    join bi.support_ratings r 
    on sra.response_id = r.response_id
    and r.survey_id = sra.survey_id
    join bizdw.support_labels_assigned_v2 l
    on l.fk_case_id = r.pk_case_id
where r.date_submitted >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
and a.start_date < '2014-01-22'
and a.end_date is null
and exists (select * 
from bi.support_ratings r2 
where r2.pk_case_id = r.pk_case_id 
having count(label_name) >= '2')
group by a.public_name, label_name
order by a.public_name, format(avg(r.rating),2), label_name desc
```

but it's to be filtering out a lot of labels that have a count of more than 2.

I know that in order to limit the labels to 10 per agent I need a subquery, but when I try this:

```
select a.public_name, label_name, format(avg(r.rating),2) as 'average', count(label_name)
from bi.support_agents_list a 
    join bi.support_ratings_agents sra 
    on a.desk_id = sra.agent_desk_id
    join bi.support_ratings r 
    on sra.response_id = r.response_id
    and r.survey_id = sra.survey_id
    join bizdw.support_labels_assigned_v2 l
    on l.fk_case_id = r.pk_case_id
where r.date_submitted >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
and a.start_date < '2014-01-22'
and a.end_date is null
and exists (select * 
from bi.support_ratings r2 
where r2.pk_case_id = r.pk_case_id 
having count(label_name) >= '2'
limit 10)
group by a.public_name, label_name
order by a.public_name, format(avg(r.rating),2), label_name desc
```

I get the a syntax error:

"ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'group by a.public_name, label_name
order
by a.public_name, format(avg(r.rating),' at line 17
Error
Code: 1064"

Any thoughts? I think I need a subquery, but I can't seem to get it to not throw an error.

Comment: `having` normally comes after `group by`

Comment: Oops that was a typo, I just fixed it. That having clause was for the subquery so it was after     group by.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can see no syntax error here :-(

Comment: Also (and incidentally), note that `'2'` is a string. `2` is an integer.